# What specialized actions do AI teammates do? Do they use their passive or active abilities?

Tags: resident-evil-orc

I noticed that the AI for the medic, Bertha, will ocassionally use the first aid spray on the player character if he/she is injured. I've noticed that no other AI character types does the same, even though healing teammates with the first aid spray can be done by any character.

**For every character type in the game, what specialized actions does the AI for each do if they are selected to be part of your team?**

In Single Player, active abilities can not be selected for AI teammates, AFAIK.  **Do AI teammates use any passive or active abilities** if they have been unlocked or selected for that character in Single Player? If yes, how do they select which active abilities to use? If no, do they have a default, fixed set of abilities that they use?